# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs Spark RDD

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to save the content of a text file in hdfs with Spark:

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

  object FormatTlfHdfs {   def main(args : Array[String]) {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Clean data")
                  .setMaster("local").setSparkHome("/usr/lib/spark")

     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

     var vertices = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/cloudera/dstlf.txt").flatMap{ 
       line => line.split("\\s+") }.distinct()
```

I'm getting the error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI,
>   no host: hdfs:///user/cloudera/metadata-lookup-tlf

Doing hdfs dfs -ls looks that is correct

```
cloudera@quickstart grafoTelefonos]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera 
Found 6 items 
drwx------   - cloudera cloudera          0 2016-02-04 18:37 /user/cloudera/.Trash 
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2016-05-02 13:38 /user/cloudera/.sparkStaging
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       1294 2016-05-02 13:34 /user/cloudera /dstlf.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error seems obvious...

> Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/cloudera/metadata-lookup-tlf

You didn't specify a host machine like

```
hdfs://quickstart:<hdfs_port>/user/cloudera...
```

You may not need the `<hdfs_port>` piece, but it doesn't hurt. I think that the correct port is 8020, so then you'd have

```
hdfs://quickstart:8020/user/cloudera...
```